# get to ckeditor in frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have an ckeditor in a frame.
If I try to do console log from browser it won't work till I inspect near the frame and do the console log again.

[this is the ckeditor]

[image]
the question is:

How can I get the first 60 char of (plaintekst) to the resume field.

I get the data with this code if I inspect near it.(it won't work right away)

```
CKEDITOR.instances.inhoud.getData()
```

Sorry if I am beeing unclear ( I am new to SO)

Answer (score 0):

You can access your iframe properties (CKEditor & etc), selecting it's object by id (for example)

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [getData method](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData) is the preferred way to get content from CKEditor, however it may be called only after CKEditor instance is ready (see [instanceReady event](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-instanceReady)):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'elementId' );
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    console.log( evt.editor.getData() );
} );
```

Looking at your description you try to call `getData` to early.